# Firebase cloud functions directory placement

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a subscription-based android app which required the used of firebase cloud functions for notification schedule.
Now I am confused about where should I create the functions directory? Should I make it in the android project directory itself or make a separate project directory for it?

Answer (score 0):

> Where should I create the functions directory?

You should create it as a sub-folder (or sub-directory) of your Firebase project folder. This way you will be able to deploy it with `firebase deploy ...`.

If you didn't choose to add Cloud Functions when you created your Firebase project, you can run `firebase init functions` in the terminal under your Firebase project main folder.

More info [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#initialize-your-project).